# Bringing Clojure to project Euler 19

Tags: programming-challenge, clojure

I recently began learning Clojure for fun, and after completing the [koans](http://clojurekoans.com/), I decide that project Euler would provide my next challenge. Here is the problem statement:

(If someone knows how to put this in spolier tags with out breaking the formatting, please feel free to edit or comment and let me know how to fix it.)

> Counting Sundays `Problem 19`
>
> You are given the following information, but you may prefer to do some research for yourself.
>
> - 1 Jan 1900 was a Monday.
> - Thirty days has September,
> - April, June and November.
> - All the rest have thirty-one,
> - Saving February alone,
> - Which has twenty-eight, rain or shine.
> - And on leap years, twenty-nine.
> - A leap year occurs on any year evenly divisible by 4, but not on a century unless it is divisible by 400.
>
> How many Sundays fell on the first of the month during the twentieth century (1 Jan 1901 to 31 Dec 2000)?

This is the code I used to arrive at the solution. Note that I purposely avoided the date/time APIs so I could try more of the language features out.

```
(ns euler.n19)


(def week-days (cycle [:mon :tue :wed :thr :fri :sat :sun]))

(defn leap-year?
  ([year] (if (= 0 (mod year 100))
            (= 0 (mod year 400))
            (= 0 (mod year 4)))))

(def months [:jan :feb :mar :apr :may :jun :jul :agu :sep :oct :nov :dec])
(def month-length {:jan 31 :feb 28 :mar 31 :apr 30 
                   :may 31 :jun 30 :jul 31 :agu 31
                   :sep 30 :oct 31 :nov 30 :dec 31})
(def leap-year-month-length (assoc month-length :feb 29))

(def years (->> (range 1901 2001)
               (map (fn [yr] (if (leap-year? yr) 
                               leap-year-month-length 
                               month-length)))))

(defn zip
  ([coll-1 coll-2] map list coll-1 coll-2))

(defn count-number-of-times-day-on-nth-of-month
  ([day date]
   (->> years
        (map (fn [month-len] (map #(% month-len) months)))
        (flatten)
        (reduce (fn [[week-days num-occurrences] curr-month-len]
                  [(drop curr-month-len week-days)
                   (if (= day (nth week-days date))
                     (inc num-occurrences)
                     num-occurrences)])
                [(drop 1 week-days) 0])
        (second))))

(defn main ([]  println (count-number-of-times-day-on-nth-of-month :sun 0)))
```

In particular, I'm wondering how the `reduce` in `count-number-of-times-day-on-nth-of-month` could be clarified since it looks very messy to me.

(As an aside, after a few hours of pouring over this and the koans, I noticed that it is now very hard to type my other code correctly :)

Answer (score 2):

A function that gives you the sequence of month lengths in a given `year`:

```
(defn month-seq [year]
  (map
    (if (leap-year? year) leap-year-month-length month-length)
    months))
```

... is all that your `count-number-of-times-day-on-nth-of-month` function needs.

- I've extended it to accept a `year-range` as well as `day` and
  `date`.
- I've replaced

  - `flatten` with the simpler `mapcat` and
  - `reduce`  with `reductions`, to simplify the algorithm.

The result is ...

```
(defn count-number-of-times-day-on-nth-of-month
  [year-range day date]
  {:pre [(>= (first year-range) 1900)]}
  (let [month-lengths (mapcat month-seq (range 1900 (inc (last year-range))))
        day-seqs (reductions
                   (fn [s n] (drop n s))
                   week-days
                   month-lengths)
        first-days (map first day-seqs)]
    (->> first-days
         (drop (+ (* 12 (- (first year-range) 1900)) date))
         butlast
         frequencies
         day)))
```

For example,

```
(count-number-of-times-day-on-nth-of-month (range 1901 2001) :sun 0)
```

---

*Odds and ends*

- Your `zip` function (unused) and `main` function are each missing a pair of parentheses.
- If there is only one arity, there is no need for parentheses around
  the argument list and body.

For example,

```
(defn zip
  [coll-1 coll-2] (map list coll-1 coll-2))
```

---

Edited to correct a sign error in dealing with the `date` argument to `count-number-of-times-day-on-nth-of-month`.

Answer (score 1):

My previous answer

- needlessly departs from the original and
- fails to expose its problems.

Let's have another go.

The function `count-number-of-times-day-on-nth-of-month` has one or two problems:

- The start day, 1 Jan 2001, is a Tuesday. This drops from the sky. It
  isn't derived from the given fact that 1 Jan 2000 is a Monday.
- In the `reduce`

  - The initial week day is not tested. It should be.
  - The final week day is tested. It should not be.

The one-off errors don't affect the problem case, because neither the initial nor final values fall on a Sunday.

---

Let's put the function into better shape.

- Replace the hazardous `flatten` with simple `concat`.
- Fuse it into the preceding `map` to make a `mapcat`.
- Keywords are functions. So we can use `month-len` as such in the
  `mapcat` function.
- Move the `nth` out of the loop into the initial `drop`.

This give us

```
(defn count-number-of-times-day-on-nth-of-month
  [day date]
  (->> years
       (mapcat (fn [month-len] (map month-len months)))
       (reduce (fn [[week-days num-occurrences] curr-month-len]
                 [(drop curr-month-len week-days)
                  (if (= day (first week-days))
                    (inc num-occurrences)
                    num-occurrences)])
               [(drop (inc date) week-day-cycle) 0])
       (second)))
```

Now we split the complex `reduce` into a `reduction` followed by a series of simple sequence functions.

```
(defn count-number-of-times-day-on-nth-of-month
  [day date]
  (->> years
       (mapcat (fn [month-len] (map month-len months)))
       (reductions
         (fn [week-days curr-month-len] (drop curr-month-len week-days))
         (drop (inc date) week-day-cycle))
       butlast
       (map first)
       (filter #(= day %))
       count))
```

This is slower but clearer. It isn't quite the same, as it correctly considers the initial value. However, we still have to chop off the final one. The requisite `butlast` has to come between the `mapcat` and the `filter`.

---

I've said that the code is flawed. This is difficult to prove. However, I found a way to frame the algorithm to make it easier to test.

The idea is to pass the calendar information into the function as a configuration object. We build up the standard calendar as follows:

```
(def standard-months [:jan :feb :mar :apr :may :jun :jul :agu :sep :oct :nov :dec])

(def non-leap-month-lengths
  (into {}
    (map
      (juxt identity #(case %, (:sep :apr :jun :nov) 30, :feb 28, 31))
      standard-months)))
(def leap-month-lengths (assoc non-leap-month-lengths :feb 29))

(defn standard-month-lengths [year]
  (if (leap-year? year) leap-month-lengths non-leap-month-lengths))

(def standard-calendar
  {:year-zero 1900
   :week-days [:mon :tue :wed :thr :fri :sat :sun]
   :months standard-months
   :month-lengths standard-month-lengths})
```

Then the general function becomes

```
(defn count-week-days-on-month-day
  [calendar [from-year up-to-year] month-day]
  (let [{:keys [year-zero week-days months month-lengths]} calendar]
    (->> (range year-zero up-to-year)
         (mapcat (comp #(map % months) month-lengths))
         (drop (+ (* (count months) (- from-year year-zero))))
         butlast
         (reductions
           (fn [wds cml] (drop cml wds))
           (drop (dec month-day) (cycle week-days)))
         (map first)
         frequencies)))
```

This

- drops the months preceding `from-year` explicitly;
- delivers the map of frequencies of *all* the `week-days`;
- starts with the first of the month at number `1`.

The problem solution becomes

```
(defn count-number-of-times-day-on-nth-of-month [week-day month-day]
  (week-day (count-week-days-on-month-day
              standard-calendar [1901 2001]
              month-day)))

(count-number-of-times-day-on-nth-of-month :sun 1)
```

This produces the same answer as before, but the general function is easier to test. For example, ...

```
(def test-calendar
  {:year-zero 100
   :week-days [:doh :rae :me]
   :months [:yip]
   :month-lengths (constantly (constantly 1))})

(count-week-days-on-month-day test-calendar [100 110] :rae 1)
;{:doh 4, :rae 3, :me 3}
```

Notice that

- the frequencies add up to 10 - correct;
- the frequency of `:doh` is greater, as it should be.

This suggests that this code is correct and the original code is flawed.

---

*Notes*

- 1900 is not a leap year.
- So 1 Jan 2001 is 365 days after 1 Jan 1900.
- `(mod 365 7)` is `1`.
- So 1 Jan 2001 falls one week-day later than 1 Jan 1900, a Tuesday.

Comment: Thanks for the review! Sorry about not voting. I forgot about this post, and it got lost in my message inbox.

Comment: @JAtkin No worries. I learned a lot doing this.